# pylint E1101:Class 'User' has no 'objects' member

Tags: python, visual-studio, django

Estou utilizando o vscode juntamente com o DjangoRestFramework e o mesmo está acusando erro na seguinte linha:

```
res = User.objects.filter(user_nome=value)
```

Porém o código roda corretamente, o erro que o editor mostra é o seguinte:

```
pylint E1101:Class 'User' has no 'objects' member User: User
```

No stack em inglês tem as seguintes perguntas relacionadas:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115977/using-pylint-with-django/2456436

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135263/class-has-no-objects-member

Porém não obtive sucesso.

Tentei `pip install pylint-django` tanto no ambiente virtual quanto na minha maquina sem sucesso.

Tentei  `pylint --load-plugins pylint_django` também sem sucesso

Tentei colocar isto nas configurações do vscode,

```
{"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
     "--load-plugins=pylint_django"
],}
```

Ele parou de acusar este erro, mas começou a acusar vários outros, como pedir ponto e vírgula no final de uma instrução python.

Tentei `pylint --ignored-classes= User` 
Ele me retorna o seguinte

```
No config file found, using default configuration
************* Module User
F:  1, 0: No module named User (fatal)
```

Versão do sistema, Uso Fedora `Red Hat 8.1.1-1`.

```
pylint --version
No config file found, using default configuration
pylint 1.9.2, 
astroid 1.6.5
Python 2.7.15 (default, May 16 2018, 17:50:09)
```

O problema continua quando eu uso outra classe no lugar de User

Answer (score 1):

A classe User no models.py precisa ter o atributo user para funcionar. 
Caso possua, coloque dunderscore entre o nome do atributo e o filtro.

```
res = User.objects.filter(user__nome=value)
```

Comment: Caso possua, coloque dunderscore entre o nome do atributo e o filtro. 
Não entendi. 
A classe User tem o atributo user_nome. 
class User(models.Model):
    user_nome = models.CharField(max_length=45)